# Easy iteration for php in class function

Tags: javascript, php, class, loops

I'm trying to create a nice and easy iterator and it worked at first, then I realized I'd need more information for the function so I tried to extend it and well it did not work.

**Example Usage**

```
$easyCMS->iterate($post,
     echo $content[0];
     echo $content[1];
 );
```

**Class Function**

```
public function iterate($d,$fn){
   $this->item = $d;
   foreach($this->item as $post){
     echo $fn;
   }
}
```

**Current Index.php Usage**

```
$post = $easyCMS->my_query('SELECT * FROM  `newsPost`');
//returns array
$easyCMS->iterate($post,
   $content[0]."<br>",
   $content[1]."<br>",
   $content[2]."<br>",
       $content[3]."<br>",
       $content[4]."<br>",
);
 //$post would be the first argument and after that would be what we want our function to do.
```

I get the error =>

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in .../index.php on line 23
```

Which I know that it's the constant `$content[num]` but I'd like to know how I'd do this for I know I could with JavaScript using the call method.

My database table looks something like

id: 1 == content: "Whats up" == ...etc

I want my code to iterate over these so then I can write like so

```
$easyCMS->iterate($post,
  '<div class="hello">'.$content[0].'</div><div id="post_'.$content[1].'"><div class="content">'.$content[2].'</div>'
);
```

Comment: `iterate($d,$fn)` — What does `$fn` stand for? And your code isn't syntactically valid. The `;`s need to be removed.

Comment: Oh yeah see I'm used to javascript and I know it's not right even for js but usually we do `,function(){...});` but I hope you catch my drift on what i'm doing, and $fn would be whatever the user puts I use fn as `function`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the best way for an easy iterator, took me some time but I finally solved it.

**Class Function**

```
public function iterate($d,$fn){
     foreach($d as $item){
        $txt = str_replace('{author}',$item["author"],$fn);
    $txt = str_replace('{id}',$item["id"],$txt );
    $txt = str_replace('{content}',$item["content"],$txt);
    $txt = str_replace('{date}',$item["date"],$txt);
    echo $txt;
   }
}
```

**PHP page IE index.php**

```
$post = $easyCMS->my_query('SELECT * FROM  `newsPost`');
$easyCMS->iterate($post,'<div class="hello">{author}</div><div id="post_{id}"><div class="content">{content}</div></div>');
```

`$easyCMS->my_query` is just a regular query which returns specific information

**my_query**

```
public function my_query($sql)
{
     $array=array();//add an array
    $query = mysqli_query($this->connect,$sql);
    if($query > 0){
    $c = mysqli_num_rows($query);//get how many rows there are
    if($c > 1){//if greater than one push into the array
      while($fetch = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){//while loop to push
        array_push($array, $fetch);
      }
      return $array;
    }else{
     return mysqli_fetch_row($query);//rows is only one
    }
    }else{
    return "No such query";//if the query does not exist!
    }
}
```

Comment: I updated my answer in regards to you posting and accepting this answer. Food for thought

Answer (score 1):

the error is caused by:

```
$easyCMS->iterate($post,
   $content[0]."<br>";
   $content[1]."<br>";
   $content[2]."<br>";
   $content[3]."<br>";
   $content[4]."<br>";
);
```

which should be

```
$easyCMS->iterate($post,
   $content[0]."<br>",
   $content[1]."<br>",
   $content[2]."<br>",
   $content[3]."<br>",
   $content[4]."<br>"
);
```

i don't think that this code solves your needs

Comment: Yeah probably not, you know what I'm trying to do? I hope someone does because I haven't done much php iterations so it's all new to me

Comment: Ok by adding the `,` it did work, but it's only parsing the `"<br>"` and nothing else. Like I said I'm new

Comment: @EasyBB: What *exactly* are you trying to do then?

Comment: I'll try updating my Original Post so you can hopefully understand a little better.

Comment: I ways able to iterate the array as suspected, but now it won't actually collect the data.

Answer (score 0):

Can't help but think you're over-complicating things here.

If you're using an array without an index key then it would be as simple as:

```
public function iterate($d,$fn){
     foreach($d as $content){
        echo $content;
     }
  }
```

Only if an index is key=>pair do you need to it like:

```
foreach ($d as $key=>$value) {
stuff//
}


$easyCMS->iterate($post,
  '<div class="hello">'.$content[0].'</div>
  <div id="post_'.$content[1].'"><div class="content">'.$content[2].'</div>'
);
```

Is wrong. When using " and ', you want to wrap ' inside of the ".

If, what you want is to irerate through a loop inside a loop, you'd want something like:

```
Foreach($post as $pos) {
$class->some_func($pos);
}

public function some_func ($post) {
/formatting.
echo $post;
/formatting.
}
```

The simplest I can come up with, based on your code currently is:

```
foreach($stuff_from_database_call as $content) 
echo "formatting stuff". $content . "/close formatting";
```

Technically you could 1 line it, so long as dont mind using . to join strings :)

Note the lack of [0] [1] etc, which is un-needed, since you are iterating through the array. However, if it was a key=>pair you'd do it like this:

```
foreach($stuff_from_database_call as $key=>$content) 
echo "formatting stuff". $key[$content] . "/close formatting";
```

Updated this after you wrote out and accepted your own answer. Instead of:

```
public function iterate($d,$fn){
     foreach($d as $item){
        $txt = str_replace('{author}',$item["author"],$fn);
    $txt = str_replace('{id}',$item["id"],$txt );
    $txt = str_replace('{content}',$item["content"],$txt);
    $txt = str_replace('{date}',$item["date"],$txt);
    echo $txt;
   }
}
```

I'd suggest something more like:

```
public function iterate($d,$fn){
    foreach($d as $item=>$value){
    $txt = str_replace('{$value}',$item[$value],$fn);
    echo $txt;
   }
}
```

This will make it a LOT more flexible, as you can easily add fields, without having to touch the function itself. When coding, ALWAYS try and do so with as much forethought as you can, so you save yourself headaches down the road.

Either way, glad you got it sorted, and glad you came back to post your sollution.

1 last afterthought. Try naming your variables a little more reader friendly :) $d is nowhere near descriptive enough. Just another avoidable headache, for yourself and for anyone else having to look at your code :)

Comment: Please see why I am "over complicating things" i updated towards the end of what the final result should in fact look like... BTW thank you for clarify the differences between the two, key pair and what not! I was confused originally.

Comment: yeah see I don't want to use the foreach I'd rather use `easyCMS->iterate($post,...)` so that it can always be dynamic. I'm getting closer just seems as though I am missing something here

Comment: Instead of passing a set of strings to the iterator function as the second argument, try passing the results as an array.

Comment: Oh ok so so `$value` being whats in the SQL return? because if so please let me know I like that a lot better and will mark yours as correct. Remember I am new, and no one ever sees my codes except for SO

Comment: Your content really didn't work the way mine did. if you see below, the iterator has to know what it's looking for. How would it know what the $value is